# Actiiviti Business Process engine: Extend the REST api

Tags: jakarta-ee, activiti

I want to create some new REST resources. For example to list all next possible tasks on a work flow.

I want to create my own war which could be deployed in Glassfish 4. (payara).

What deps do I need ? How can I create new endpoint urls ?

Answer (score 0):

The Activiti REST application is written using Spring MVC. By default, the org.activiti.rest.service.api is component-scanned (see https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/blob/master/modules/activiti-rest/src/test/java/org/activiti/rest/DispatcherServletConfiguration.java#L25).

So, if you put a custom class with the proper Spring MVC annotation in the same package, you have a custom endpoint where you can implement what you want.

It's not necessary to change the war file for this, you just have to make sure the new class is on the classpath of the application.

Comment: This means I can create a jar package with a class under the same package as activitii source and put it inside the rest war and deploy.

Comment: Will my resource also be protected like general activiti resources ?

Comment: Your Rest endpoints are protected by the configuration in the SecurityConfiguration class. You can manage the level of protection for any Rest endpoint from this configuration class.

Comment: By protection I mean the default activiti Roles and Rights. I don't want to implement it again for my resource.

Comment: If you use the same url patterns /service/xxx, then yes. Otherwise you'll need to add some configuration like Greg mentions.

Comment: What spring dependencies do I need for that ? Is there any example available for such an extension ?

Comment: The above mentioned approach doesn't work. my rest resource is not being called.

Comment: Can you add the code of the rest controller that you're trying to add.

Answer (score 0):

**Activiti** is just a jar and Community has provided much APIs to work around it. but you can use Spring to write your own logic around activiti. basically it uses DB to process/transfer state which any other workflow would do. so first provide a DB and populate necessary schemas/tables into it. next select your UI (i would highly recommend AngularJS being one of the most used frameworks these days). define your Architecture as how your UI is going to interact with Activiti. beware, it's gonna take a **lot of time**

Answer (score 0):

Rangalo,

Below is a sample Rest endpoint for you.

```
package com.bp3.tupac.rest;

import com.bp3.tupac.service.ServiceException;
import com.bp3.tupac.service.InfoService;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/tupac")
public class VersionRestController {

    /**
     * @return Some stuff
     * @throws ServiceException
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/info",
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        method = RequestMethod.GET
    )
    public InfoService.Info getTupacInfo() throws ServiceException {
        try {
            return new InfoService().getTupacInfo();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ServiceException("Failure getting Tupac info....dog", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you need to make sure you application configuration is setup to include this package in the component scan.
To do this, add the package to the component scan directive in your DispatcherServletConfiguration class.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(existing packages, "com.bp3.tupac.rest"})
```

After that, you should be able to call the path : http://host:port/context/tupac/info

And find out who killed Tupac.

Hope this helps.
Greg